# Android: Which Launch Mode is best for Activity with Foreground Service and Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, launch, foreground-service, launchmode

I'm confused with the launchMode options for the Manifest file, even with the description on the Android page.

My goal is to develop an app, that sends a notification after a certain amount of unlocks per time (30mins), but also after a certain screen time. Therefore, in **onCreate of the MainActivity, a foregroundService is started**, which is supposed to constantly run in the background.
To listen to the user actions, I have registered an IntentFilter with the corresponding actions and my BroadcastReceiver class in MainActivity. In my Receiver class, I catch the actions in if-conditions.

I only have two Acitivities, LoginActivity -> MainActivity, which holds the foregroundService and several Receivers.

It seems that **my MainActivity is created several times** in the whole process. And it seems that with this, my **Receiver-class also triggers multiple times**, which I want to avoid to prevent errors. So I'm wondering, which launch mode do I need for my MainActivity?

Maybe you need completely different informations, then I'm happy to share them!

Comment: What launches `MainActivity`? Is this the launcher `Activity` (with CATEGORY=LAUNCHER and ACTION=MAIN in the manifest)?